# Disable action button when textinput is empty in Shiny app [R]

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm building a shiny app in which a query from `textInput` is made when the user clicks on the "search" action button. I'd like that button to be disabled if the `textInput` box is empty. I'm using `shinyjs::toggleState()` here, but I can't figure out what logic it needs to apply to see that the text box is empty. In my reproducible file below, the logic I put in place is `is.null(input$query)`. I've also tried with `is.na(input$query)`, `length(input$query) == 0`, and `input$query == ''`, all without success What should I put there instead?

Here's the app.r file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      textInput(inputId = "query", label = "Enter query:", value = ""),
      actionButton(inputId = "search", label = "Search", icon = icon("search"))
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    toggleState("search", !is.null(input$query))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Use `toggleState("search", input$query != "" | is.null(input$query))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this do?

```
 observe({
    if(is.null(input$query) || input$query == ""){
      disable("search")
    }
    else{
      enable("search")
    }
  })
```

As per @Sagar you can also do:

```
observe({
  toggleState("search", input$query != "" | is.null(input$query))
})
```

or

```
observeEvent(input$query,{
  toggleState("search", input$query != "" | is.null(input$query))
})
```